# count of unique values in pandas dataframe column

Tags: pandas, numpy, unique

I am trying to find the frequency of unique values in a column of a pandas dataframe I know how to get the unique values like this:

```
data_file.visiting_states()
```

returns :

```
array(['CA', 'VA', 'MT', nan, 'CO', 'CT'],    dtype=object)
```

and I want to return the count of those unique values and I know I cant do .value_counts() because its a numpy array

Comment: *I cant do .value_counts() because its a numpy array*, just cast it to series! `pandas.Series(my_array).value_counts()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html):

```
data_file = pd.DataFrame({'visiting_states':['CA', 'VA', 'MT', np.nan, 'CO', 'CT','CA',
                                             'VA', 'MT', np.nan, 'CO', 'CT']})
print (data_file)
   visiting_states
0               CA
1               VA
2               MT
3              NaN
4               CO
5               CT
6               CA
7               VA
8               MT
9              NaN
10              CO
11              CT

print (data_file.visiting_states.nunique())
5

print (data_file.visiting_states.nunique(dropna=False))
6

arr = np.array(['CA', 'VA', 'MT', np.nan, 'CO', 'CT'],    dtype=object)
print (arr)
['CA' 'VA' 'MT' nan 'CO' 'CT']

print (len(arr))
6
```

Comment: I want to know the count per state, ie 5 for CA, 4 for VA etc

Comment: Then need [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) -  `print (data_file.visiting_states.value_counts())`

Comment: this did not work, it said value counts is not defined

Comment: ok, what return `print (type(data_file.visiting_states))` and what `print (type(data_file.visiting_states.iloc[0]))` ?